# kivy camera apply filter in real time

Tags: python, camera, kivy

it's possible with the kivy camera api to capture a camera photo or video and apply filter in real time ? for example modify all pixel for reverse color ? or modify all pixel for apply black and white filter ?

actually i can create window and view camera image in real time :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


kv = ''' 
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: 399, 299

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        Button:
            text: 'Start'
            on_release: camera.play = True

        Button:
            text: 'Stop'
            on_release: camera.play = False
'''


class CameraApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CameraApp().run()
```

but it's possible to intercept signal and apply custom effect ?

thanks for advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with the camera's [`Texture`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html#kivy.graphics.texture.Texture) if you are familiar with these concepts. Retrieving it is very simple as well, just call `camera.texture` where needed.

I prefer to work with [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) myself and display the results later. You can find many examples on how to embed their format in kivy, using previously mentioned `Texture`, for example [here](https://gist.github.com/ExpandOcean/de261e66949009f44ad2).

Comment: thanks very much, This is exactly what I was looking for